# How to retrieve cookies of API using Ruby/Capybara

Tags: ruby, cookies, cucumber, capybara, session-cookies

I'm testing a API Service using Ruby Cucumber. The webpage is authenticated and the cookies gets changed after X minutes. So everytime to run the tests, i manually go to webpage and take the cookie from developer console. Is there anywway to automate this in my Ruby code ? Please advise.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How to read cookies depends on which driver you are using, but there is a gem called `show_me_the_cookies` that provides a normalized API across most of the available Capybara drivers - https://github.com/nruth/show_me_the_cookies